# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout CardView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i'm trying to inflate a `CardView` with information taken from `FireBase`. My problem is that the reference to the database read it but the `RecyclerView` miss to get it... I'm new on Android, i'll aprecite so much your help.

This is my Java Class:

```
public class ResumenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference refMV;
RecyclerView recyclerViewResumen;
ArrayList<Listado> listaResumen;
AdaptadorResumen adaptadorResumen;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resumen);

    recyclerViewResumen = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listadoRecyclerView);
    recyclerViewResumen.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    refMV.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listaResumen = new ArrayList<Listado>();

            Listado l = dataSnapshot.getValue(Listado.class);
            listaResumen.add(l);

            adaptadorResumen = new AdaptadorResumen(ResumenActivity.this, listaResumen);
            recyclerViewResumen.setAdapter(adaptadorResumen);
            recyclerViewResumen.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ResumenActivity.this, "Upss.. Algo anda mal!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

This is the Model:

```
package app.technologias8.smartbarprototipo.modelos;

public class Listado {

private String Nombre;
private String Precio;

public Listado() {
}

public Listado(String nombre, String precio) {
    this.Nombre = nombre;
    this.Precio = precio;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.Nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.Nombre = nombre;
}

public String getPrecio() {
    return this.Precio;
}

public void setPrecio(String precio) {
    this.Precio = precio;
}
}
```

The Firebase:

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVwuC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add just a layout manager to your `Recycleview` like this

```
refMV.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listaResumen = new ArrayList<Listado>();

            Listado l = dataSnapshot.getValue(Listado.class);
            listaResumen.add(l);

            adaptadorResumen = new AdaptadorResumen(ResumenActivity.this, listaResumen);
            recyclerViewResumen.setLayoutManager(ResumenActivity.this);//ADD THIS
            recyclerViewResumen.setAdapter(adaptadorResumen);
            recyclerViewResumen.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RecyclerView` needs an adapter, even an empty one, in order to perform its layout properly. Since your database call is happening asynchronously, the `AdaptadorResumen` that it creates in `onDataChange` is not ready in time for android to do its initial layout, so the whole thing is ignored.

Try setting a null adaptor in `onCreate`. It will be replaced when your database call is complete.

```
recyclerViewResumen = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listadoRecyclerView);
recyclerViewResumen.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
adaptadorResumen = new AdaptadorResumen(ResumenActivity.this, null);
recyclerViewResumen.setAdapter(adaptadorResumen);
```